# Getting SUM from 2 different tables into one result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I have been trying to get this to work for 12 hrs now and I cannot :-( Can someone please show me how I can get the `ssnumber` to group and get the total for each `ssnumber`.

Here is what I have now. In Table number 1 I have this code

```
SELECT 
    UNIT_NO, SUM(RATEB) AS TOTALRTE 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE 
    TRUCK_PAID = 1 
    AND PICK_UP_DATE >= '(fromdate)' 
    AND PICK_UP_DATE <= '(todate)'
GROUP BY 
     UNIT_NO
ORDER BY  
     UNIT_NO
```

But table number 2 is where the `ssnumber` column is, so what I'm trying to do is the rateB sum from all of the loads for each unit_no and then group them and then go into table number 2 and group the ssnumber with the unit number from table number 1 and sum the rateB from table number 1.

Something like this (see below) but its not working :-(

```
SELECT 
    UNIT_NO, SUM(RATEB) 
FROM 
    TABLE1 
WHERE 
    TRUCK_PAID = 1 
    AND PICK_UP_DATE >= '(fromdate)' 
    AND PICK_UP_DATE <= '(todate)' 
GROUP BY 
    UNIT_NO 
JOIN 
    TABLE TABLE1.UNIT_NO = TABLE2.UNIT_NO GROUP BY TABLE2.SS_NUM
```

or

```
SELECT 
    UNIT_NO, SUM(RATEB) AS TOTALRATE 
FROM 
    TABLE1 
GROUP BY 
    UNIT_NO 
JOIN 
    TRUCKS ON (TABLE1.UNIT_NO = TABLE2.UNIT_NO) 
GROUP BY 
    TABLE2.SSNUMBER
```

Thank you guys so much for any help...

Comment: What is table 2?  Can you show your table structure and sample data, and desired output?

Comment: I'm trying to get the total (sum) from table1 by grouping the field Unit_No and getting the total (sum) from the field called rateb, then I want to go into table2 and match up the Unit_No with the Unit_No field in table2 and then group the results by the ss_Num field

Comment: so both table1 and table2 have the field name Unit_No I just want to maybe Join ? then together so that i can group them by the ss_num and get the total (sum) and not by the Unit_No

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, it is hard to really understand what you are trying to accomplish without more info about table2 and maybe an example of what you are expecting. However, what I got from your description is that you are trying to accomplish something like this?

```
SELECT UNIT_NO, TOTALRTE, TOTALLDSRTE
FROM
(
    SELECT UNIT_NO,SUM(RATEB) AS TOTALRTE 
    FROM LOADS 
    GROUP BY UNIT_NO
) AS tbl1
JOIN
(
    SELECT SS_NUM, SUM(RATEB) AS TOTALLDSRTE
    FROM LOADS
    GROUP BY SS_NUM
) AS tbl2
    ON tbl1.UNIT_NO = tbl2.SS_NUM
```

Comment: in table1 I want to group by unit_no and get the total (sum) that is in the field named rateb. in table2 I want to group by ss_number and then somehow join? table1 via the unit_no and then output the results that are grouped by the ss_number

Comment: something like this (see below) but its not working :-(  SELECT UNIT_NO,SUM(RATEB) AS TOTALRATE FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY UNIT_NO JOIN TRUCKS ON (TABLE1.UNIT_NO=TABLE2.UNIT_NO) GROUP BY TABLE2.SSNUMBER

Comment: So, all you want is to join them it seems? Then just join your grouping:
    SELECT UNIT_NO,SUM(RATEB) AS TOTALRATE 
    FROM TABLE1 

        JOIN TRUCKS ON (TABLE1.UNIT_NO=TABLE2.UNIT_NO) 
    GROUP BY UNIT_NO,TABLE2.SSNUMBER
If that is not correct, then I think a quick example using data would be best

Comment: i'm getting this error when I try it: Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'UNIT_NO'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Ambiguous column name 'UNIT_NO'.

Comment: how do i give you a example using data ?

Comment: @compcobalt: The error message should be clear enough. You are pulling a `UNIT_NO` column without specifying which one, because both tables have got a column with that name. Just stick a table's alias (any of the two will do here) before the column name: `SELECT TABLE1.UNIT_NO, …`.

Comment: Ambiguous means that both tables have the same column, you need to change UNIT_NO to tbl1.UNIT_NO. As to the data example. Edit your original questions and list out a couple sample rows for each table and then what you expect the query to do with those rows.

Comment: yea your are right guys it's a simple error and everything works now.. I been up for god knows how long trying to get this working so it looks like it's time to go to sleep now. Thank you so much for all of your help guys, i don't know what i would have done without your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead of getting data from two select queries in one select query, try to fetch them as separate queries. This saves a lot of time. That, or you can create a table for the result and update the result of each query into the table.